# Best approach to replace 0 with amount, when user enters an amount in edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am working on app where an edittext is having $0 as pre-defined text.
Zero is editable. But as soon as user enters an amount like $80, its showing $080.
I am using textwatcher to non deleted $ and replaced at time of printing value.

How can i achieve the output as $80 when user is typing an amount

preset value - $0
after typing $80, 
Output = $080
Expected = $80

Thanks in advance.

```
   amountEdittext.setText("$0");
    Selection.setSelection(amountEdittext.getText(), 
 amountEdittext.getText().length());
    amountEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().startsWith("$")) {
                amountEdittext.setText("$");
                Selection.setSelection(amountEdittext.getText(), amountEdittext.getText().length());

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Use a regex to extract the value (080 whitout $), cast the value to int, and reformate the text to put the $ and the value casted to int

Comment: why want to put the $ symbol inside the edit text? why don't try to put the $ symbol in a  TextView before the EditText?

Comment: @Darish its a field of amount and in centre of edittext should be start with $0 and replace with the actual amount

Comment: Well, then simply check the text value by using amountEdittext.getText(), If it starts with a $, then simply do nothing, otherwise simply add $ symbol before the String and set it back to the EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your question.

```
    amountEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (editable.length() > 2) {
                for (int i = 0; i < editable.length() - 1; i++) {
                    if (editable.charAt(i) == '$' && editable.charAt(i + 1) == '0') {
                        editable.delete(i + 1, i + 2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the text property you should **HINT**

```
amountEdittext.setHint("$0");
```

you will no longer require any other code.
and keep the text blank you can then add validation to check for empty text.

you can change the hint when it has focus using `setOnFocusChangeListener()`

Comment: hint won't work properly cause it will send the $0 to top of edittext.

Comment: yes if you are using material text input but you to do that you can add an event setOnFocusChangeListener and change the hint

Answer (score 0):

Better use a InputFilter than using `TextWatcher`. Since you've the **$** sign better to remove it from the `EditText` and use one `TextView` along with `EditText` horizontally. So that you can get rid of the dollar sign

```
class DecimalDigitsInputFilter(digitsBeforeZero: Int, digitsAfterZero: Int) : InputFilter {
private val mPattern: Pattern

init {
    mPattern =
        Pattern.compile("[0-9]{0," + (digitsBeforeZero ) + "}+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero ) + "})?)||(\\.)?")
}

override fun filter(
    source: CharSequence?,
    start: Int,
    end: Int,
    dest: Spanned?,
    dstart: Int,
    dend: Int
): CharSequence? {

    if (source != null && dest != null) {
        val replacement = source.subSequence(start, end).toString()
        val newVal = (dest.subSequence(0, dstart).toString() + replacement
                + dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length).toString())
        val matcher = mPattern.matcher(newVal)
        if (matcher.matches())
            return null

        return if (TextUtils.isEmpty(source))
            dest.subSequence(dstart, dend)
        else
            return ""
    }
    return ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized what you are doing, `Selection.setSelection` moves the cursor to the end of text in the edittext,so that will be after zero.

So, here is a solution that i think would work;

```
    amountEdittext.setText("$0");
    amountEdittext.setOnFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        if (b && amountEdittext.getText().toString().matches("^\\$0$")) {
            amountEdittext.setText("$");
            Selection.setSelection(amountEdittext.getText(), amountEdittext.getText().length());
        } else {
            Selection.setSelection(amountEdittext.getText(), amountEdittext.getText().length());
        }
    }
```